# usage of subordinate conjunction which

Tags: conjunctions

Consider the following short reading :

> He now plainly saw that he was no better than a murderer; the
>    extreme anguish of **which** discovery making life insupportable, he
>    fell upon his sword.

To me, **which** discovery = such a discovery = He now plainly saw that he
was no better than a murderer.

That is, I don't know why we use **which** *instead of adjective such*.

Comment: I agree with you. _Which_ looks wrong, especially when placed beside _discovery_, since it seems like _which_ refers to it. Maybe someone else can provide clarity.

Comment: There's no conjunction. "Which" is a determinative here, and together with "discovery" they form the phrase "which discovery" that functions as the relativised element whose interpretation is given by the antecedent "he was no better than a murderer".

Comment: It's as BillJ says. And if you were to use 'such' you would need an 'a' after it: ". . . the extreme anguish of **such a** discovery making life insupportable . . ." (But perhaps you don't like 'a'. There should be one before 'murderer' too!)

Comment: @Old Brixtonian : Thank you for your pointing.